# Getting an array of a capture group's matches

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to capture the names of every method in a source file using Ruby, because I want to learn Ruby better. I've never used regex in Ruby, only Perl, so bear with me.

I'm using this regex pattern:

```
/\w* (.*)\([\w| |,]+\);/
```

which should capture the method name in a C method declaration, for example the mult in this line:

```
int mult ( int x, int y );
```

I want to get an array of every method name in the source file.

I tried this:

```
sourceCode.scan(/\w* (.*)\([\w| |,]+\);/)
```

And it returns an array of single element arrays containing all the matches, but there has to be a better way to get it in a 1D array than unwrapping that.

Does anybody know of a better way to get a 1D array of global capture group matches?

Comment: Sure, you can use `.flatten` to unnest the arrays.

Comment: Please post the return value of `scan`

Comment: @PinnyM Aha flatten gets exactly what I want. I'm starting to really like Ruby...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is only nested if you use capture groups, so if you want a flat array you could design a regexp without any capture groups. This can be done using positive look-ahead `(?=pat)` and look-behind `(?<=pat)`:

```
sourceCode.scan(/(?<=\w)\s.+?(?=\s?\([\w| |,]+\);)/)
```

That begin said I think the flatten method (as mentioned in the comments) is the way to go as it is more readable and the regexp above should not really see the light of day.